# Como limpar campos input após submit?

Tags: php, jquery, html5

É o seguinte: quando você envia o formulário, no método [POST], as variáveis estarão incapsuladas na barra de URL. Já no método [GET] as variáveis ficam expostas no barra de URL. No entanto, quando atualizar a página no método [POST] ficam armazenadas as variáveis e reenvia o formulário. Como resolver?

Answer (score 1):

Vi que você colocou nas `tags` o jQuery, então você pode usa-lo, assim não terá problemas, um exemplo simples de utilização é.

```
// PHP
$retorno = array();
$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?");
$sql->execute(array($_POST['id'])); 

$retorno['dados'] = $sql->fetchAll();

die(json_encode($retorno))
```

Com isso, seu PHP já ira retornar um `json` para o seu `ajax` que ficará assim...

```
function listarUsuarios(){
   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'SUA URL DO ARQUIVO PHP',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
         id: 1
      },
      success: function(data){
          console.log(data)
          $('body').append('<h1>'data.nome'</h1>')
      }
   })
}

// Aqui você executa sua função
listarUsuarios()
```

E dessa forma você resolve seu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Enfim como resolve?

Basta você criar essa function, :

```
// Limpar URL
function removeURL($url, $titulo){
  echo 'window.history.pushState("'.$url.'", "'.$titulo.'", "'.$url.'");
}
```

Logo em seguida você criar o seguinte código:

```
//Limpar METHOD POST
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
 removeURL($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'Aqui você digita o Titulo da Página');
}
```

Comment: Por favor explique melhor sua solução.

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução seria como coloquei no esquema abaixo: receber o formulário via POST, fazer o que deve ser feito, criar uma SESSION como resultado do processo e depois fazer um redirecionamento para a própria página. Desta forma, se a tecla F5 for apertada, não haverá novo submit dos dados:

O esquema seria assim (é apenas um conceito esquemático):

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
// SE EXISTE POST E A SESSION ESTÁ VAZIA, ENTRA NESTE IF
if (isset($_POST) && SESSION == ""){
   // 1. recebo os dados do formulário
   // 2. faço o que tem que fazer com os dados
   // 3. crio uma SESSION com "ok" ou "erro"
   // 4. faço um redirecionamento para a própria página
         Header("Location: pagina.php");
}
?>

<?php
// SESSION CHEIA

// Mostro a mensagem de acordo com o valor da SESSION:

if (SESSION == "ok"){
    echo 'Dados cadastrados com sucesso';
}else if (SESSION == "erro"){
    echo 'Houve um erro';
}

Apago a SESSION;
?>

</body>
</html>
```